# How i handle the game continue and external events in android(Andengine)

Tags: android, andengine

I am developing the game using andengine.

How i handle the game continue options after redirect to home screen(press home key ) but the timer in running in background.

How to handle the external events (Incoming calls, sms). In j2me i used hideNotify and show Notify . How i make in andengine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make all of actions that will save the state of your app in **onPause()** method of the Activity. This method calls when the new activity put in the head of activity stack.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read this article containing the fundamentals about the activity lifecycle which pretty much covers all you need to know about how to handle an application going into background, exiting, coming back to front: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle